# GitLab ci cannot start bash in container

Tags: bash, docker, gitlab-ci-runner

Good day!
I am using `powershell` shell executor for `gitlab runner`. For the test I need to `run bash in my php-fpm container` but I get a strange error

> docker exec -it phpfpm bash

> ###### error:
>
> the input device is not a TTY.  If you are using mintty, try prefixing the command with `winpty`

also i tried to run command with winpty prefix

> winpty docker exec -it phpfpm bash

> ###### or
>
> winpty -Xallow-non-tty docker exec -it phpfpm bash

but "winpty" is not internal or external
command, executable program, or batch file.

i installed git with standard windown shell option instead of MTY
also i tried to install winpty but it didn't work. Are there any options to solve this problem or what could be the problem?

Comment: The error comes from the `-t` flag, which is not supported by Docker for Windows. Would the mere command `docker exec -i phpfpm bash` suffice?

Comment: Otherwise you might want to install [winpty](https://github.com/rprichard/winpty) (normally provided in Git-Bash for Windows) manually.

Comment: [ErikMD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9164010/erikmd) thank you! it work